# Accessing variables outside class

Tags: function, class, variables, constants, global

I will try to explain my issue as good as I can.
I have a class with functions, the purpose of one function is to fetch information from the database and display it. 
Everything works as it should, but now I need to access some variables to use them outside my class in another file, I don't know how this should be done so I'm wondering if someone can guide me.

```
        function fetch(){
    $this->_select_query = '
                            SELECT movies_id, movies_title, movies_director, movies_year, movies_category_id, cat.name 
                            FROM movies 
                            LEFT JOIN cat ON id = movies_category_id' 
                            or die(mysqli_error());

      $this->_stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare($this->_select_query);
      $this->_stmt->execute();
      $this->_stmt->bind_result($this->_select_id, $this->_select_title, $this->_select_director, $this->_select_year, $this->_select_category_id, $this->_select_category_name);
      $this->_stmt->store_result();
        while($this->_stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$this->_select_title.'</td>
                    <td>'.$this->_select_director.'</td>
                    <td>'.$this->_select_year.'</td>
                    <td>'.$this->_select_category_name.'</td>
                    <td><a href="index.php?form=edit&amp;id='.$this->_select_id.'" title="Edit movie">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                  </tr>
            '; 
        }
}//close function fetch
```

The function fetch is inside a class called movies, now on another page I have a form to edit(update) these movies and I would like to return the title, director etc.. inside that form so it is easy to notice what you are changing.

Now I do know how to do this using php procedural but not with object oriented php.
As you can also notice here I echo out the whole table (another part of the table is on a diffirent page) 
So because of this I can't use $movies->fetch()

I do hope someone can give me some more information on my issue since I feel a bit lost at this point, and while staring too much on the same code you can become confused and mix up stuff.

Kind Regards

Edit: should I be using globals, constants ?

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code.

As you are saying, you can't do `$movies->fetch()` since it echoes the table. That's a sign of braking the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You should divide your function into two: one function that fetches (and returns) the data, and another one that takes data as a parameter and returns a table with the data.
That way, you can reuse the first one when you want to get the values for the edit form.

Since you have a procedural background, I'd recommend that you create a new class that represents a "movie" that has the required fields. Then, for each row in your table you should create an instance of that class and populate the fields, and ultimately return all those instances.

Sorry for not posting any code at the moment, I realized that would have been easier.